# Reachability Class always returns Reachable

Tags: reachability

I'm using the `Reachability` class from [apples demo projects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) to ping some servers pages. But no matter what I write in URL I always get `ReachableViaWiFi`.

```
Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:URL];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

I'm connected to a Wifi, but I just want to check if some servers are available or not. (With the answer "NO" if I'm disconnected from the net).

Any suggestions please, even with others classes with the same goal.

Thanks

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html):

> A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an
>   application into the network stack, can leave the local device.
>   Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be
>   received by the host.

**Edit**: So, if there is a route available (whether the server is actually listening or not), it return that route's quality, in your case WiFi.

How about just sending your request and checking out the result?

As to your question for another library: Those questions are deemed [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The fact is, that i don't know what kind of server i will get at that point, so i need to do a generic "ping" to test his "operativity" (more then reachability). Is there a class who allow me to do that? (synchrounosly)

Comment: First of all, do not network on the main thread. Also, you can do low level networking with CoreFoundation (CFNetworking). For third-party libraries, refer to the "off-topic" part of my answer.